# StreamWrite Writing garbage text to the existing file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am writing text to an existing log file with StreamWritter and Files.AppendAllTextMethod but it is writing garbage to file.

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream((string)_logger.ConfigPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(message);
        }
```

but the text I see in log file
汰⁺牷瑩⁥瑩汰⁺牷瑩⁥瑩

I am not sure what is the issue, and how can I get it fixed?

NOte : when am writing text to some other text file , it is working perfectly fine.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what text are you trying to pass it? Are you sure it is `utf8`?

Comment: I tried encoding later, initially there was no encoding parameter supplied, edited the question too!!

Comment: Your question is still missing what text you are trying to write without this, its not possible to provide any kind of solution.

Comment: What are you using to view the contents of the text file?

Comment: This is not garbage, it's chinese ;). Do you experiencing the same behavior with entirely new file ? What does message contains ? Have you checked your encoding ?

Comment: Text is "Please Write here", it 's just for testing :)
I am opening the file manually to view the content, and when am trying to write it to some other file, or entirely new file it is showing the text in english :)

Comment: Need to look at what is creating the file in the first place and if there is any data in this file already.  E.g. if the file is being opened and is written to as a binary file or as an encrypted file, then after this you are appending some text, you may end up not being able to read the text.

Comment: If you're just appending text, you might find [File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx) is quicker and easier to use. You could consolidate all that code into just File.AppendAllText((string)_logger.ConfigPath, message);

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem with binaryWriter, StreamWriter and mostly it happens with first line only. Garbage value is added at beginning of file automatically. My guess is it has something to do with GC. I used `File.AppendAllText` and `File.WriteAllLines` that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the Encoding you are using. It happened to me I was using:

```
File.WriteAllLines(PATH, ArrayOfStrings, Encoding.UTF8);
```

this added some garbage to the begining of the first line "ï>> ?". Changing the encoding to:

```
File.WriteAllLines(PATH, ArrayOfStrings, Encoding.Default);
```

Solved the problem.